# Generate .json file with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm trying to generate a json file with PHP with the code below and I'm getting an empty array -> {"posts":[]}. I'm using Wordpress. Can someone assist me. Thanks

```
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts"); 

    $response = array();
    $posts = array();
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    $url['url']=$row; 
    $title['title']=$row;

    $posts[] = array('url'=> $url, 'title'=> $title);

    } 

    $response['posts'] = $posts;

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you get data back from the query?

Comment: You are calling `mysql_query()` _twice_. And the second time, when you try to get the result set, you are calling it on the result from the first `$sql`.  Turn on error reporting and display_errors, and you'll see PHP complain about that.

Comment: What @MichaelBerkowski said, also you assign $url and $title to the array $row.

Comment: yes, the query is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code! Please check this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts");

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$response[$i]['url']  = $row['url']; 
$response[$i]['title']= $row['title'];
$data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
$i=$i+1;
} 

$json_string = json_encode($data);

$file = 'file.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it returns several nulls. Like -> {"posts":[{"url":null,"title":null},...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');    
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts"); 
$response = array();
$posts = array();
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
  $posts['url']=$row['url'];; 
  $posts['title']=$row['title'];
  array_push($response, $posts);
} 
$json = json_encode($response);
$file = 'file.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

Reference: visit [here](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/08/php-mysql-json-file-creation-dynamically.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your while loop. Try this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $url=$row['url']; 
    $title=$row['title'];

    $posts[] = array('url'=> $url, 'title'=> $title);
}
```